# PictureBox continues loading after closing the form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, picturebox

I have a form(Images) that is called from another form(Main). The Images form uses a flow layout which holds together custom usercontrols. The usercontrol has  a picturebox which uses the `PictureBox.LoadAsync()` method to get an image from a URI. The problem is that the network activity does not stop after closing the Images form.

I have tried handling the `UserControl.Disposed` event to do a `PictureBox.CancelAsync()` on the picturebox, but to no avail. What should I do so that the loading stops if the Images form has been closed.

Comment: @GrantWinney, already tried that

Comment: Just a doubt, the PictureBox resides in the UserControl. How do you call its CancelAsync from the form?

Comment: No, did not work, actually what I meant was is it alright "programatically" to   break into some other objects space?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

It's possibly not the most clever solution, but this works for me:

Call this function from form_Closing event:

```
Private Sub closeformdisposingpictureboxes(f As Form)
    For Each c As Control In f.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is PictureBox Then
            Dim pbox As PictureBox = CType(c, PictureBox)
            pbox.Image.Dispose()
        End If
    Next
    f.Close()
    f.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: Not enough programmers write this kind of code, even though they always should.  Do favor either the FormClosed or Disposed event, given that FormClosing can be cancelled.  And make sure that the image isn't used anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'PictureBox.CancelAsync()' to the form's Closed event handler. You have no control of when Disposed event will fire.

Comment: Just a doubt, the PictureBox resides in the UserControl. How do you call its CancelAsync from the form.